# Remover informações de dentro de um array com angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, table, ng-repeat

Tenho um array com algumas informações e que vem sempre com 4 números na frente dos names:

```
 {id: 1810, name: "2652joaodasilva", username: "", password: ""}
 {id: 2744, name: "3704DiegoSerri", username: "", password: ""}
```

Gostaria de remover esses 4 números, tentei de algumas formas com o limitTo, mas só consegui cortar de outros jeitos, estou usando o ng-repeat para exibi-los em uma tabela:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="clientes in list_clients">
      <td class="text-center">{{clientes.name}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o filtro `limitTo` não é possível, quando `limitTo` é usado para strings, ele retorna uma string contendo apenas o número especificado de caracteres.

Você pode utilizar o método [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
{{clientes.name.substring(4, clientes.name.length)}}
```

ou o método [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
{{clientes.name.slice(4, clientes.name.length)}}
```